# sliderCursor not staying in slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom range slider. I'm having trouble keeping the slidersCursor in the slider.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var cursorPosition = 1 - clamp01((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention);
sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention - cursorRadius) + 'px)';
```

With the code above, when you drag the slider to the far right or left, the cursor goes halfway out of the slider on either side.

When I remove `- cursorRadius`, it goes too much to the right side. It stays in the slider when you drag to the left, but when you drag it to the right, it goes out of the slider.

When `cursorRadius` is equal to `cursor.offsetWidth`, it goes too much to the left side.

How can I make the sliderCursor stay in the slider when you drag to the far sides?

(Please don't post any JQuery or other "you can use 'this' plugin" answers. I'm doing this for learning purposes, and I want to create my own. Thanks!)

#### JSFiddle

```js
function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0];

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentTarget = null;
    var sliderWithDescendents = wrapperElem.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderWithDescendents.length; i++) {
      sliderWithDescendents[i]
      if (sliderWithDescendents[i] === e.target || wrapperElem === e.target) {
        currentTarget = wrapperElem.children[0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentTarget === null) return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);
    sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var cursorPosition = 1 - clamp01((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention);
    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention - cursorRadius) + 'px)';
  }

  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}

var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);






function clamp01(val) {
  return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, val));
}

function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 62px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition * (sliderDimention - cursorRadius*2)) + 'px)';`

You need the radius times x2 then the brackets are to perform the operations first then multiply by cursorPostions (which is from 0 to 1);

Although it works, I'd try clamp the final value (from [0 + radius] to  [dimension - radius]). That way you won't get this weird drag where the mouse is in the left or right of the scroll_cursor. You want the mouse to be in the center of it at all times.

If you are doing it for learning, dissect [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/)? It's very well coded.

```js
function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0];

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentTarget = null;
    var sliderWithDescendents = wrapperElem.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderWithDescendents.length; i++) {
      sliderWithDescendents[i]
      if (sliderWithDescendents[i] === e.target || wrapperElem === e.target) {
        currentTarget = wrapperElem.children[0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentTarget === null) return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);
    sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var cursorPosition = 1 - clamp01((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention);
        sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition * (sliderDimention - cursorRadius*2)) + 'px)';;
  }

  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}

var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);






function clamp01(val) {
  return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, val));
}

function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 62px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you please explain what you mean by: 'clamp the final value (from [0 + radius] to [dimension - radius])'?

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/ed7poetn/1/) Actually, it had to be different than what I thought but same idea. I've added a standard clamp function at the bottom. Read its description. I then clamp the final location, not the 0 to 1 value.

Comment: Thanks! Really like this answer! Going to upvote it!

Comment: One more question.... I'm trying to get the value of the cursors position. I tried doing: `console.log((cursorPosition / sliderDimention) * 100);`, but it isn't 1 - 100, it's (rounded)  -1 - 99. How can I get it from 1 - 100? (I can ask a new question if you want...)

Comment: Use this `console.log( Math.round( cursorPosition / (sliderDimention-cursorRadius*2) * 100) );` [Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/ed7poetn/2/)